# "Nothing is a subclass of every other class", how to understand it?

Tags: scala

These days, I am reading the book "programming in scala". There is one sentence in the book on Page 246, Chapter11, first paragraph:

> For example, just as Any is a superclass of every other class, Nothing
>   is a subclass of every other class.

I understand the first part because every class inherits Any in a direct or indirect way. But I can't understand the latter part of the sentence.

This is class Nothing definition:

```
abstract final class Nothing extends Any
```

Comment: @Rahul I don't think this is a duplicate. He isn't asking about multiple inheritance, he asking to understand what `Nothing` means.

Comment: In short: the book is wrong. `Nothing` is a sub**type** of every other **type**. Type != class.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Conceptually, `Nothing` is something that is harder to grasp than `Any`, which we're familiar with from Java and most other object oriented programming. `Nothing` is Scalas [bottom type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bottom_type). The definition from Wikipedia states:

> In subtyping systems, *the bottom type is the subtype of all types*.
>   (However, the converse is not true—a subtype of all types is not
>   necessarily the bottom type.) **It is used to represent the return type
>   of a function that does not return a value**: for instance, one which
>   loops forever, signals an exception, or exits.

I think the easiest way to reason about it is to think of it as a way of describing something that never returns. You can't construct an instance of a `Nothing` type yourself. One particular use of `Nothing` in Scala is to be able to reason about covariant parametric types:

> In Scala, the bottom type is denoted as `Nothing`. Besides its use for
>   functions that just throw exceptions or otherwise don't return
>   normally, it's also used for covariant parameterized types. For
>   example, Scala's `List` is a covariant type constructor, so
>   `List[Nothing]` is a *subtype of `List[A]` for all types A*. So Scala's `Nil`,
>   the object for marking the end of a list of any type, belongs to the
>   type `List[Nothing]`.

---

Being a *subtype of* is not the same as being a *subclass of*. From [Subtyping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subtyping):

> Subtyping should not be confused with the notion of (class or object)
>   inheritance from object-oriented languages; subtyping is a relation
>   between types (interfaces in object-oriented parlance) whereas
>   inheritance is a relation between implementations stemming from a
>   language feature that allows new objects to be created from existing
>   ones. In a number of object-oriented languages, subtyping is called
>   interface inheritance.

This is also denoted in the [Scala Specification Section §3.5.2](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/03-types.html#conformance) (Conformance) as part of the `<:` (is subtype of relation), both for value types and type constructors:

> - For every value type `T`, `scala.Nothing <: T <: scala.Any`.
> - For every type constructor `T` (with any number of type parameters), `scala.Nothing <: T <: scala.Any`.

One familiar aspect of subtyping is variance of generic types, where `-` denotes contravariance and `+` denotes covariance.